# Kind elasticsearch doesnt launch any pods?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have a simple yaml file

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: transit-monitor
spec:
  version: 7.9.2
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: LoadBalancer
  nodeSets:
  - name: elasticsearch
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

I was noticing that when i say `kubectl get elasticsearch` it will display:

```
NAME                 HEALTH   NODES   VERSION   PHASE   AGE
transit-monitor                       7.9.2             8m18s
```

It doesn't give any health info or nodes.

I was trying to figure out what to do.  I was deleting them with a simple `kubectl delete elasticsearch` and then reapply the yaml file, but it doesn't do anything.

Givens:

I am on a mac, so I run through though `minikube`, which is fine as it connects to `kubectl`.  I don't see any issues with this though being the case.  My next step might be delete and reinit the minikube vm.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deleting the minikube instance, and went through the following steps before it getting resolved.

```
minikube delete
minikube start
# Added Definitions
kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/1.2.1/all-in-one.yaml
kubectl apply -f .
```

Then everything was initializing as usual.